# How Can I independent the views in a layout

Tags: android

How can I move views independently from other views in a layout ? For example, I want to be able to move one button up without the other moving but, currently, they are both moving. For more information please see the following image:

[image]

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />
```

Comment: you use relative layout, the green button is set to rightOf red button. so, if you any thing change in red button it affect the green button.

Comment: just remove the  android:layout_toRightOf="red button id" in green button att

Comment: Please don't add crap to the post to get around the character limit. That is just distracting and makes your post worse. Instead, find a way to describe your problem and current outcome better.

Answer (score 1):

First you not posted complete xml layout file. How can some some know what layout you are using.
Solution:You need to put both buttons in different layout if your are using `LinearLayout` or you can use `Relative Layout` but in `Relative Layout` case both buttons should not be depend on each other.

Comment: I use `RelativeLayout` in the `xml` file and only there are this buttons in the `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to embed the components you want.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardholderNameText"
                        style="@style/form_label"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/cardholder_name" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: relativeLayout doesn't have orientation